# countdown via objective c

Tags: objective-c, countdown

Okay, so I've been learning objective c and I want to make a countdown starting with the number 22 and counting down to 2. I've successfully made a count up starting at 2 and going to 23, but when i try to use -- instead of ++ for the countdown, there's no output.

## import

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

```
@autoreleasepool {

    int y;
    for (y=23; y<3; y--)
    { NSLog(@"%i",y);}

}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
for (y=23; y>3; y--)
```

The problem is that the condition `y<3`, which you had in your original code, is never met. A for loop is continuously run until that condition returns false; when you initialize `y` to 23 and check if it's less than 3, the loop will never run to begin with.

Comment: thanks dude, so when i insert y>2, it counts down to 3. Doesn't the computer normally read y>2 as any number greater than 2,Not just 3?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. You're confusing me a bit, sorry- what're you expecting the output to be? Counting down to 3 sounds right. Unless you just want it to include 2; in that case, y>=2 is what you're looking for.

Comment: so normally the expression y>2 includes ANY number greater than 2. With this loop, y>2 includes 3, the number directly above 2

Answer (score 0):

In your program, y is never less than 3, which is why it never executes. Your countdown will start with 23 as you have it written currently.

Change to `for (y=22; y<3; y--)`

Comment: thanks, how would i make this program count down by 5. If I try entering y-5, it gives me an error statement

Answer (score 0):

y initialize value is 23 , is never less than 3, so you should use `for (y=22; y>=2; y--)`
,thus the result will from 22 count down to 2

Comment: you said you want make countdown from 22 to 2, so `y>=2` is the condition for end of loop